# How to make three DIV align vertical if not enough space horizontal

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following DIV in my asp.net page:

```
<div style="width: 98%; padding: 2%; overflow: auto; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 32%;">
        <CMS:ContentBlock ID="ContentBlock2" runat="server" CssClass="test1 green" DefaultContentID="638" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 32%;">
        <CMS:ContentBlock ID="ContentBlock3" runat="server" CssClass="test1 green" DefaultContentID="638" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 32%;">
        <CMS:ContentBlock ID="ContentBlock4" runat="server" CssClass="test1 green" DefaultContentID="638" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is generated like this in HTML:

```
<div style="width: 98%; padding: 2%; overflow: auto; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 32%;">
            <div id="ContentBlock2" class="test1 green">
    <p align="center"><span class="info" align="left"><strong>Regular Hours:</strong><br />Monday&#160;- Friday: 8am - 9pm<br />Saturday&#160;&amp; Sunday: 9am - 5pm</span> <br /><span class="info" align="left"><a title="Most Insurance Plans Accepted" href="/participating_insuran">Most Insurance Plans Accepted</a><br />914-848-5644</span></p>
</div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 32%;">
            <div id="ContentBlock3" class="test1 green">
    <p align="center"><span class="info" align="left"><strong>Regular Hours:</strong><br />Monday&#160;- Friday: 8am - 9pm<br />Saturday&#160;&amp; Sunday: 9am - 5pm</span> <br /><span class="info" align="left"><a title="Most Insurance Plans Accepted" href="/participating_insuran">Most Insurance Plans Accepted</a><br />914-848-4544</span></p>
</div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 32%;">
            <div id="ContentBlock4" class="test1 green">
    <p align="center"><span class="info" align="left"><strong>Regular Hours:</strong><br />Monday&#160;- Friday: 8am - 9pm<br />Saturday&#160;&amp; Sunday: 9am - 5pm</span> <br /><span class="info" align="left"><a title="Most Insurance Plans Accepted" href="/participating_insuran">Most Insurance Plans Accepted</a><br />914-848-45455</span></p>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.test1
{
    text-align: left;
    background: #b6ff00;
}
.test1 p
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Seeing it in a desktop browser is fine where it is across the screen:

[image]

When I make the browser smaller  it is displayed like this:

[image]

What I am looking to do is after a certain breakpoint of width, I would like them to go vertically instead of keep squeezing them as shown in the second image. Pretty much I want them to stack one below the other vertically.

How do I make them go vertically as the browser size gets smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to set **100% width** to your div at a certain **browser width**.

**Example:**

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px)
{
  .test1
  {
      width:  100%;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/31xqrk9d/

Comment: How will it know when to move the second DIV below the first and the third DIV below the second?

Comment: Setting div **width** to 100% will give a full row to each div at the specified size.

Comment: if `.test1` has a width of 100%, the floated div's will fill up the width of the parent block and naturally form a top-to-bottom layout.

Comment: I know I can use a Bootstrap but I am just trying to customize it myself. When I tried the Bootstrap it was causing some issue with some of my other CSS :/

Comment: You don't have to implement bootstrap, media queries are native css properties.

Comment: Please try with `width: 100% !important` in order to override inline rule.

Comment: I will do a JSFiddle because it is not working for me :/

Comment: I think because it is a nested DIV, it wasn't working. Let me test it out. Thanks.

Comment: You have to set the rule to `.submain` to override the 32% width. Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/z0qaz2f7/3/